# Adjust size of legend ticks

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to make the coloured lines in the legend thicker, as they are too hard to distinguish now. I tried using `override.aes` inside the `scale_color_manual` function, or inside the `guides` function, but either does nothing, or increases the size of the legend, but not of the ticks themselves. I've also tried playing with different value sizes in `scale_shape_manual` but also to no avail. Here is a sample of my code below.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(countrycode)

set.seed(123)

temp <- data.frame(
  Year = rep(1995:2020, times = 12), 
  Country = rep(c("ABW", "AFG", "AGO", "AIA", "ALB", "AND", "ANT", "ARE", "ARG", "ARM", "AUT", "ETH"), each = 26), 
  deg_in_norm = runif(12 * 26, min = 0, max = 1), 
  deg_out_norm = runif(12 * 26, min = 0, max = 1) 
)

highlighted_countries <- c("ZAF", "SAU", "RUS", "IRN", "IND", "ETH", "EGY", "CHN", "BRA", "ARG", "ARE")
temp <- temp %>%
  mutate(Color = ifelse(Country %in% highlighted_countries, as.character(Country), "Not BRICS")) %>%
  mutate(Size = ifelse(Country %in% highlighted_countries, 1, 0)) %>%
  mutate(Full_names = ifelse(Country %in% highlighted_countries, 
                             countrycode(Country, origin = 'iso3c', destination = 'country.name'), 
                             "Not BRICS")) %>%
  group_by(Country) %>%
  mutate(id = cur_group_id()) %>%
  ungroup()

ggplot(data = temp) +
  geom_line(aes(x = Year, y = deg_in_norm, 
                color = factor(Color), size = factor(Size), group = id)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("ARE" = "black", "ARG" = "#6699CC", "ETH" = "#44AA99",
                                "Not BRICS" = "grey"),
                     labels = c("United Arab Emirates", "Argentina", "Ethiopia",
                                "Not BRICS")) +
  scale_size_manual(values = c("0" = 0.5, "1" = 1.5), guide = "none") + 
  guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = 15) ) ) +  
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
  labs(y = "Normalised In-Degree\n")
```

This gives this picture:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should listen to your warning messages:

> ```
> Warning message:
> Using `size` aesthetic for lines was deprecated in ggplot2 3.4.0.
> ℹ Please use `linewidth` instead.
> This warning is displayed once every 8 hours.
> Call `lifecycle::last_lifecycle_warnings()` to see where this warning was
> generated.
> ```

Changing `size` to `linewidth` does the trick:

```r
ggplot(data = temp) +
  geom_line(aes(x = Year, y = deg_in_norm, 
                color = factor(Color), linewidth = factor(Size), group = id)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("ARE" = "black", "ARG" = "#6699CC", "ETH" = "#44AA99",
                                "Not BRICS" = "grey"),
                     labels = c("United Arab Emirates", "Argentina", "Ethiopia",
                                "Not BRICS")) +
  scale_linewidth_manual(values = c("0" = 0.5, "1" = 1.5), guide = "none") + 
  guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(linewidth = 15) ) ) +  
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
  labs(y = "Normalised In-Degree\n")
```

[image: Plot with thicker lines in the legend]

Comment: I had tried with linewidth and it didn't work either. The key was to add scale_linewidth_manual as well, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You need `lwd` instead of `size`.  So:

```
guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(lwd= 2) ) ) +
```

[image]